# Will Get Items be able to search all the records inside SharePoint list or it will only search the first 100,000 items

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have a large SharePoint list with around 2.5++ million items >> and I defined to only get the items with Status = "Active" and order the items by Modified data in descending order, as follows:

[image]

And I defined the Pagination of 100,000 items, as follows:

[image]

So how the Get Items will work internally in this case? Will it only search the first 100,000 items (order by Modified desc) and get the ones with status = "Active"? or it will be able to search the 2.5 items, and get the related ones with Status = "Active" + Order by "Modified desc"?

Comment: Check my test results in answer below. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but it is important information related to processing large sets of data in Power Automate.

There are limits on how many items the "Apply to each" action can process in a single flow run. The limits are 5,000 items for a flow without a premium license and 100,000 items for a flow with a premium license.

There are also limits on the number of actions a flow can run every 5 minutes and every 24 hours. These runs are counted for all types of actions, including connector actions, HTTP actions, and built-in actions from initializing variables to a simple compose action. The 24 hour period limits are 10,000 actions for flows without a premium license and 100,000 actions for flows with a premium license.

For more information, see [Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698).

Comment: thanks for the reply ..but using an office 365 admin account which does not have a premium license i were able to run 100,000 items inside foreach.. not sure if there is a real limitation inside foreach for non-premium accounts

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test from my end and found that Power automate flow was able to iterate through all list items in large SharePoint list and return the list items with specified filter and sort queries in Get items action.

Below are test results:

**List data**:

[image]

**Flow configuration**:

[image]

**Flow run output**:

[image]

Comment: so what could be the reason that it is not working in my case?

Comment: Make sure you have indexed Status and Modified column.

Comment: How many items are there in the list with Status=Active? Also use single quote (like `'Active'`) in filter query.

Comment: Does this answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.